# Encontrando brackets através da API do Atom

Tags: api, coffeescript, atom

Usando o editor de código [Atom](https://atom.io/) tive a ideia de fazer uma feature simples porém útil para o mesmo. Porém para isso o primeiro passo é encontrar o inicio do escopo, para isso procuro um par de [brackets](https://github.com/atom/bracket-matcher). A função pode ser acessada usando `Ctrl+m`.

A questão é que como visto no link anterior o Atom já tem uma classe implementada com um método para encontrar os brackets, porém eu não encontrei nenhuma referência a isso na [API](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.1.0/Atom) oficial e acho que fazer um `fork` do projeto como sugerido em outra [pergunta semelhante](https://discuss.atom.io/t/accessing-the-bracketmatcher-object-from-its-package/19381/6) no fórum por causa de um método não vale a pena.

As dúvidas são as seguintes:

- Existe uma função parecida com essa na `API` ou realmente preciso fazer um `fork` apenas por causa de um método?